# How can i output hadoop result in csv format

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce

I need to output my hadoop result in .csv format.
how will i do this?
My code :https://github.com/studhadoop/xml/blob/master/XmlParser11.java

should i simply include csvoutputFormat in my code.
I am using mapreduce API

myjob.sh

```
bin/hadoop jar /var/root/ALA/ala_jar/clsperformance.jar ala.clsperf.ClsPerf /user/root/ala_xmlrpt/Amrita\ Vidyalayam\,\ Karwar_Class\ 1\ B_ENG.xml  /user/root/ala_xmlrpt-outputshell4

bin/hadoop fs -get /user/root/ala_xmlrpt-outputshell4/part-r-00000 /Users/jobsubmit


cat /Users/jobsubmit/part-r-00000 /Users/jobsubmit/output.csv
```

**SOLUTION**

ys i was missing > in cat

```
cat /Users/jobsubmit/part-r-00000> /Users/jobsubmit/output.csv
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use TextOutputFormat. The default key/ value separator is a tab character. You can change the separator by setting the property "mapred.textoutputformat.separatorText" in your driver.

```
conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separatorText", ",");
```

Comment: Yes. And you shoulde be using "TextOutputFormat".

Comment: Watch out the property name it should be "mapred.textoutputformat.separator" not "mapred.textoutputformat.separatorText"

Comment: Yes. mapreduce is good. I just realized that I mentioned property name wrong in my first response. It should be "mapred.textoutputformat.separator"

Comment: But for CSV Format - text will be in double quotes and the comma and integer will be with out quotes. Am i right?

Comment: I have answered the header related query against the same query. Regarding the format of the CSV file, it will have the comma separation but nor sure if it will enclose the data in double quotes. You can try an example and see.

Comment: Actually my intension is to make the output of hadoop result to .csv.bcoz i need to visualize this data.So in rapidminer we can import the data as csv. So i am trying to make my output as csv. i think it should be as .csv file.I am not sure.Any ideas.

Comment: Is there any way to make my part-00000 as part-00000.csv file

Comment: I don't think it is possible create a file with ".csv" extension from a MapReduce job. You need to have a workflow script which will 1.) Submit the MapReduce Job 2.) Which will extract the output from HDFS using shell commands 3.) Merge them together, rename as ".csv" and place in a directory where the visualization tool can access the final file.

Comment: can u jst give me an example to do the same?

Comment: hadoop jar <you job jar>.jar parameter1 parameter2
hadoop fs -get <HDFS Path to job output>/part-r-* <local filesystem Path>
cat part-r-* > <Output File Name>.csv

Comment: Have above three lines in a shell script say myjob.sh, chmod the script to executable and them run the script at Linux prompt

Comment: hadoop jar <you job jar>.jar yourJobParameter1 yourJobParameter2

Comment: hadoop fs -get <HDFSPathToJobOutput>/part-r-* <LocalFilesystemPath>

Comment: cat <LocalFilesystemPath>/part-r-* > <OutputFileName>.csv

Comment: ys executed with out any errors but when i checked the file in my local file system it is showing "The CSV file was empty and couldn’t be imported." why it is so.

Comment: whwn the shell script is executing it is displaying the output, bt my output.csv file is empty. my output is like comma seperated value.is that the reason.

Comment: Share your script. I will check if there is any issue.

Comment: Redirection is missing in the third command `cat /Users/jobsubmit/part-r-00000 >   /Users/jobsubmit/output.csv`             Note ">" in the command, which put the std output to the file.           Also use "part-r-*" so that if multiple files are there, all files are taken into consideration.

Comment: u r Welcome. Glad that it helped. Mark this as the answer to help other boarders with similar queries.

Comment: Am i able to snd this file to rapidminer for visualization:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352004/how-to-sent-csv-file-to-rapiminer-for-visualization-through-terminal

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29352/discussion-between-studhadoop-and-rags)

Comment: I want to plot graph for this data.how will i do this(Rapidminer) any idea

Comment: how visualization tool can access the final file.

Comment: @Rags Yes you can define your output extension! In your reducer, use MultipleOutputs. This write method is what you need. (I'm using it in production!): http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html#write%28java.lang.String,%20K,%20V,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: @gyabraham but they still end in r0000

Comment: @Rig yes, you cannot get rid of multiple rxxx files because every reducer creates on its own. However, you can safely merge these files after the job completes