# How to rename my hadoop result into a file with ".csv" extension

Tags: csv, hadoop, mapreduce

Actually my intention is to rename the output of a hadoop job to `.csv` files, because i need to visualize this csv data in rapidminer.

In [How can i output hadoop result in csv format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329884/how-can-i-output-hadoop-result-in-csv-format) it is said, that for this purpose I need to follow these three steps:

```
    1. Submit the MapReduce Job 
    2. Which will extract the output from HDFS using shell commands 
    3. Merge them together, rename as ".csv" and place in a directory where the visualization tool can access the final file
```

If so, how can I achieve this?

UPDATE
`myjob.sh`:

```
bin/hadoop jar /var/root/ALA/ala_jar/clsperformance.jar ala.clsperf.ClsPerf /user/root/ala_xmlrpt/Amrita\ Vidyalayam\,\ Karwar_Class\ 1\ B_ENG.xml  /user/root/ala_xmlrpt-outputshell4

bin/hadoop fs -get /user/root/ala_xmlrpt-outputshell4/part-r-00000 /Users/jobsubmit

cat /Users/jobsubmit/part-r-00000 /Users/jobsubmit/output.csv
```

showing:

```
The CSV file was empty and couldn’t be imported.
```

when I tried to open `output.csv`.

**solution**

```
cat /Users/jobsubmit/part-r-00000> /Users/jobsubmit/output.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to retrieve MapReduce result from HDFS

```
hadoop dfs -copyToLocal path_to_result/part-r-* local_path
```

Then cat them into a single file

```
cat local_path/part-r-* > result.csv
```

Then it depends your MapReduce result format, if it's already a csv format, then it is done. If not, probably you have to use other tool like sed or awk to transform it into csv format.

Comment: All are fine but when i view my .csv file in localfs the file is empty. I am also sharing my shell script.but no errors are shown.in local part-r-00000 contains text.

Comment: you need to add ">", this is output redirection, like the cat command above in my answer