# How do I output data in a MapReduce job for Sqoop to export?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

I've read a lot about importing from SQL using Sqoop, but there are only tidbits on exporting, and the examples always assume that you're exporting imported/pre-formatted data for some reason, or are using Hive.

How, from a MapReduce job, do I write data to HDFS that Sqoop can read and export?

[This Sqoop documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_file_formats) shows me the file formats supported. I guess I can use text/CSV, but how do I get there in MapReduce?

[I've found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329884/how-can-i-output-hadoop-result-in-csv-format), which says to just modify the options for `TextOutputFormat`, but just writes key/values. My "values" are multiple fields/columns!

Answer (score 0):

Try using other storages like avro or parquet (more buggy), so you have a schema. Then you can "query" those files and export their data into a RDBMS.

However, it looks like that support was a bit buggy/broken, and only worked properly if you created the files with Kite or sqoop (which internally uses kite).

http://grokbase.com/t/sqoop/user/1532zggqb7/how-does-sqoop-export-detect-avro-schema

Answer (score 0):

I used the `codegen` tool to generate classes that could write to SequenceFiles:

```
sqoop/bin/sqoop-codegen --connect jdbc://sqlserver://... --table MyTable --class-name my.package.name.ClassForMyTable --outdir ./out/
```

And then I was able to read those in using Sqoop, exporting with the bulk setting. But the performance was abysmal. In the end, I instead just wrote simple CSV-like text files importable with the BCP tool, and what took hours with Sqoop completed in minutes.